# Website not working on mobile - loads, then reverts to google search in 0.2 second

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a responsive site designed with twitter bootstrap that works fine on desktop, but not so much on mobile (tested on 2 different Android devices in Chrome and Samsung browser, and an iPhone in safari).

**What works - Mobile**

1. If I type in the url with an additional page (other than index.html), i.e. **seniorcareplacementchoices.com/learn.html** it loads just fine.

**What doesn't work - Mobile**

1. If I type in the url itself -  seniorcareplacementchoices.com (with or without www or http://) it loads for about .2 secs then goes to www.google.com.
2. seniorcareplacementchoices.com/index.html does not work either.

The only real difference between index.html and the others such as partners.html is that I added a bootstrap carousel to the index.html.

I am using site44 for hosting.

I think the problem is either:

a) The carousel is not responsive and messes up the mobile interpretation of the site
b) Something to do with google's new ssl rule (haven't looked much into it)

Any ideas?

NOTE: Yes I do have the line

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

**CODE**

index.html

```
<head>
    <title>Senior Care Choices</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/neat-purple.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" id="neat-stylesheet">
    <link href="libs/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/ico" 
      href="../img/favicon.ico">
    <!--New Stylesheets and scripts for CAROUSEL -->

    <link href="../../dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">   
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="./css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="./js/carousel.js"></script>


    <!--end new stylesheets for carousel -->

    <!-- Use google font -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic|Lustria" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

learn.html

```
 <head>
    <title>Senior Care Choices</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/neat-purple.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" id="neat-stylesheet">
    <link href="libs/lightbox/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="icon" 
      type="image/ico" 
      href="../img/favicon.ico">

    <!-- Use google font -->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic|Lustria" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


  </head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this would be your culprit:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    var isMobile =  function () {
        if(window.innerWidth <= 800 && window.innerHeight <= 600) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };
    var redirectToMobile = function () {
        if (isMobile()) {
            window.location.href = "http://google.com";
        }
    };
    redirectToMobile();
})();
```

Embedded in your "Confidence: START" area. Looks like a copy paste fail ;)

Curiously enough if you have a large (5"+) phone, this doesn't fire. My Nexus 5 didn't trigger this condition because the `innerHeight` was 640.